# Qt Signal is emitter but signal seems not triggered

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

All,

I'm developing an application and inside the app, I need to generate a signal when a value is changed. To do so I have updated my class MyDevice to add CumulChanged slots when the value data is changed.

MyDevice.cpp

```
void MyDevice::IncreaseSize(uint64_t size) {
    Device->cumulsizeoperation += size;
    emit CumulChanged();
}

void MyDevice::CumulChanged(){
    qDebug() << "test";
}
```

I'm entering in the IncreaseSize and CumulChanged is emitted.

I'm using this signal in my UI view to get the information to update a progress bar.

What I have done in UI.cpp

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(MyDevice::CumulChanged()),
        this, SLOT(onUpdateProgress()));
```

and onUpdateProgress is defined also in the UI class

```
void UI::onUpdateProgress(){
    Box->ProgressUpdate();
}
```

My UI class is defined as below:

UI.cpp

```
UI::UI(DeviceMngr& device) :
    m_device(device)
```

and UI.h

```
class UI : public QTreeWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    UI(DeviceMngr& device);
    ~ UI();

private:
    DeviceMngr& m_device;
}
```

Any Idea why the onUpdateProgress is not triggered ?

Thanks

Comment: First argument of `connect` should point to the class which has a signal, in your case it should be some pointer of type `MyDevice` and not `UI`. Also `MyDevice::` is probably not allowed and certainly not needed so you'd better remove it.

Comment: Your signal has code in it. It shouldn't. Your  connection syntax looks weird too, either use the old or the new (qt5) syntax. Looks like you didn't get signals and slots right in general.

Comment: @ddriver. I do not see what is weird. I always use the connect like this but it was only in the same classes. It the first time, I expect a signal from another class

Comment: @Predelink thanks I will remove "this" to avoid the call of a method from the same class

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have something like this in MyDevice.h:

```
signals:
    void CumulChanged();
```

Then remove:

```
void MyDevice::CumulChanged(){
    qDebug() << "test";
}
```

and add following line to UI constructor:

```
connect(&device, &MyDevice::CumulChanged, this, &UI::onUpdateProgress);
```

Comment: thanks but are you sure that we have to use so many '&' and why SIGNAL/SLOT are not in the connect command

Comment: Google Qt new signal slot syntax

Comment: I have tried all proposed solution but no one works. Here is the error:

 error: no matching member function for call to 'connect'
    connect(&device, SIGNAL(CumulChanged()),
^~~~~~~